# Gesture Handling AgmMap isn't working

Tags: angular, google-maps, typescript

I am currently using AGM Map from https://angular-maps.com/
and I want to disable the zooming function when scrolling. Even after putting the gestureHandling = "'cooperative'" it still stays the same. is there any factor that might have been the reason it doesn't take my input?

```css
.map-container {
    margin-top: 56px;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -ms-overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.main-container {
    margin-top: 56px;
    margin-left: 235px;
    padding: 15px;
    -ms-overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
agm-map{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
     margin-left: 0;
     padding: 0;
     -ms-overflow-x: hidden;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     overflow-y: scroll;
     position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;

}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .main-container {
        margin-left: 0px !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<div [@routerTransition] class="map-container">
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]='12' [gestureHandling]="'cooperative'">
    <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>

</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

without set apiVersion but setting the directive [scrollwheel]="null" has works for me!

Comment: Yes, It worked for me. Thanks for sharing the solution

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/1411

According to the issue thread, the problem isn't with the AGM module but with the google api. I was having the same problem and was able to solve it by setting the apiVersion to '3.31' in the modules 'forRoot' method:

```
imports: [
AgmCoreModule.forRoot( {
  apiKey: Globals.googleApiKey,
  apiVersion: '3.31'
} ),
```